# Center subcaption in Rmarkdown using knitr

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, tex

I have an issue using subcaption in a figure with multiple graphs using Rmarkdown. I want all my 4 graphs to be aligned and centered, but when I set fig.ncol = 1, only the last graph is centered and the 3 others are somewhat to the right.

What I already tried to fix the problem:

- replace fig.ncol = 1 by fig.sep = c('\newline', '\newline', '\newline'), but gives the same result

Here is my code:

````
---
 title: "Test"
 author: "My Name"
 output: pdf_document
 header-includes:
   - \usepackage{subfig}
---  


```{r, echo = FALSE, fig.cap = "Main Title", fig.subcap=c("Sub1","Sub2", "Sub3", "Sub4"), out.width='.30\\linewidth', out.width='.30\\linewidth', fig.asp=1, fig.ncol = 1, fig.align = c('center')}

library(ggplot2)

# line chart
 p1<- ggplot(pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) +
         geom_line()

 # step chart
 p2<-ggplot(pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) +
         geom_step()


 # line chart with points
 p3<-ggplot(pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) +
         geom_line() +
         geom_point()

 # line chart
 p4<-ggplot(pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) +
         geom_line()


 p1
 p2
 p3
 p4
 ```
````

The output looks like this:

[image: Output]

Any ideas how to get my 4 graphs centered? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ggarrange()` from the `ggpubr` package. There are various options you can adjust from there.

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, fig.cap = "Main Title", fig.asp=1}

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

par(mfrow=c(4,1))
# line chart
 p1<- ggplot(pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) +
          geom_line() + 
          labs(caption='Sub1') + 
          theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

 # step chart
 p2<-ggplot(pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) +
         geom_step() + 
          labs(caption='Sub2') + 
          theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


 # line chart with points
 p3<-ggplot(pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) +
         geom_line() +
         geom_point() + 
          labs(caption='Sub3') + 
          theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

 # line chart
 p4<-ggplot(pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) +
         geom_line() + 
          labs(caption='Sub4') + 
          theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrow=4)
````

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at this package seems to be a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

No idea which .pdf renderer are you using. Something I would do is to arrange the plots in a single grid using [`{patchwork}`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork). This way you will have only one element to arrange at rendering time.

The main difference is that you'll have to specify your plot captions when creating your plots (changing the font as you please). You'll then have to adjust `fig.width` and `fig.height` in the chunk options for proper rendering.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
    geom_smooth(aes(disp, qsec)) +
    labs(caption = "Some nice \n two line caption here") +
    theme(plot.caption.position = "plot",
          # Font family might differ depending on your machine
          plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5, family = "Free Serif"))

p4 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
    geom_bar(aes(carb)) +
    labs(caption = "Another cool caption") +
    theme(plot.caption.position = "plot",
          plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5, family = "Free Serif"))

p3 / p4
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Also a good alternative. Will have a look at patchwork package. Thanks!